Script not working when 'if' condition is added
I am trying to add a piece of schema directly as I have been unable to make it work via Yoast SEO.
If I just use the JSON array I have created the code is added, however when I add my condition by page ID it doesn't work, what have I missed?
The page is a custom post type single page.
global $post;
if( $post->ID == 1385 ){ 

    $arrJson = array(
        '@context' => 'https://schema.org/',
        '@type' => 'AggregateRating',
        "ratingValue" => "4.93",
        "bestRating" => "5",
        "ratingCount" => "18",
        "itemReviewed" => array(
            '@type' => 'Hospital',
            'name' => 'Practice Plus Group Hospital Barlborough',
            'telephone' => '0330 053 6443',
            "address" => array (
                "@type" => "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress" => "2 Lindrick Way",
                "addressLocality" => "Barlborough",
                "addressRegion" => "Chesterfield",
                "postalCode" => "S43 4XE",
                "addressCountry" => "UK"
            ),
        ),
    );

    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">';
    echo json_encode($arrJson);
    echo '</script>';
}


what you get when you echo $post->ID ?

Also, check that 1) $post is an actual object, and 2) that 1385 is the right page ID.

If I use $post->ID I get 1385

Oh, how do I add 'global $post' inside my function above? Or doesn't that matter?

Looks like $post is already available as a global variable so in theory your code should work. The fact that it doesn't seems to say that your problem lies elsewhere. How exactly are you adding this piece of code to your site?

I'm using a simple plugin that I created

If you have Yoast SEO enabled, you should be using the filters wpseo_schema_graph or wpseo_schema_graph_pieces inside your plugin as described here.

I've tried, I can't get it to work for aggregatedRating

Did you check out the link I've posted? I'm using it vor @types VideoObject and JobPosting as described and it works quite nicely. If you still can't get it to work, maybe update your question with the hook and the function now in use?

I will have another look, maybe I'm missing something
